# Not smoothy in drawing when using multithread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, console, drawing, mutex

My program has this function:
1 thread for vehicle moving and 1 thread for user_input and 1 thread for using that input to move the people.
And after 1 step, I will draw the vehicle and people. If I use single-threading, then it works. And when I use multi-threading, it sometimes crash and the display of people and vehicle is not smooth.
[image]

this is my code

```
void CGame::startGame()
{

    char user_input;
    bool input_ready = false;
    bool draw_finish = true;
    setGame();

    CPeople people;
    //g.runGame();


    char inp;
    condition_variable cv, cv2;
    mutex m;

    thread t1([&cv, &m, &user_input, &input_ready, &draw_finish, &cv2]() {

        while (true) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
            cv2.wait(lock, [&draw_finish] {return draw_finish; });
            user_input = CConsole::getInput();
            input_ready = true;
            draw_finish = false;
            cv.notify_one();
        }
        });

    thread t3([&people, &cv, &m, &user_input, &input_ready, &draw_finish, &cv2]() {

        while (true) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
            cv.wait(lock, [&input_ready] { return input_ready; });
            people.peopleMoving(user_input);
            //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
            draw_finish = true;
            input_ready = false;
            cv2.notify_one();
        }
        });
    //INPUT.get();
    mutex m2;
    thread t2([this, &m2, &cv, &draw_finish]() {
        //  unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
        m2.lock();
    this->runObstacle();
    //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
    m2.unlock();


        });

    //while (true) {
    //  inp = CConsole::getInput();
    //  people.peopleMoving(inp);
    //  //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds());


    //}

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    //
}
```

The draw funtion is just erase the old position and print at the new position.

Comment: Please read [mre].

Comment: We don't have enough here to actually run it ourselves. But the first thing you should do is add try-catch and try to print stack traces so you have an idea of where it's crashing. Or run it from a debugger. "It's crashing" isn't that useful to use.